# Component won't change with React router dom

Tags: reactjs

I have an "Header" component and two more components that I want to show on it each at a different condition.

```
renderUserHeader = () =>{

    if(sessionStorage.getItem('user-auth')){
     var tokenToSend = {token: sessionStorage.getItem('user-auth')}
    var regJSONED = JSON.stringify(tokenToSend)

    fetch('http://localhost:4000/users/token', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body:  regJSONED,

    }).then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
        }
        return response.text(); 
    })
    .then(data => {
   let JsonedUserName = JSON.parse(data)
   this.setStateUserName(JsonedUserName.name)

    })

    return <UserHeader name ={this.state.userName}/>

} else if(!sessionStorage.getItem('user-auth')){
return   <Link to="/login"> <LoginLink /> </Link>
}
}
```

As you can see component "UserHeader" will show only if 'user-auth' is exist in session storage, and component "LoginLink" will be showed if 'user-auth' doesn't exist.

Every time I delete 'user-auth' from the session-storage "LoginLink" is immediately being showed instead of "UserHeader", but every time "user-auth" is being created at the storage-session I must refresh the page so "UserHeader" can be showed up instead of "LoginLink".

How do I make "UserHeader" being shown immediately when "user-auth" is created?
Did I do something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can do setInterval to check if session storage data changed or not, better was doing this is using useEffect from React Hooks https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects